# Matplotlib: Printing plot to pdf file : not working with figure()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying plotting multiple pandas data frames to a single pdf file by:

```
def plot_user_data(df):
    fig = plt.figure()
    df.plot(x = 'm_srcaddr')
    plt.xticks(df.index, df['m_srcaddr'], rotation=90)
    fig.suptitle('User Data Usage for ')
    return fig
```

for multiple df I am calling ::

```
    plot = plot_user_data(df)
    pdf = PdfPages('foo.pdf')
    pdf.savefig()
```

Above code is creating a pdf file without plot and per page title only.

How ever if I change the function like:

```
def plot_user_data(df):
        fig  = df.plot(x = 'm_srcaddr').get_figure()
        plt.xticks(df.index, df['m_srcaddr'], rotation=90)
        fig.suptitle('User Data Usage for' )
        return fig
```

I am not able to figure out why first function is not plotting actual plot.? Now I want to change the size of each figures as I am not aware how to change fig size in second function.